# Unity GameObject doesn't exist in when building the app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

**What is happening?**

I have a UI GameObject in my scene. When I run the game in the Editor, the object shows and everything is fine, but when I try to Build my App, the UI doesn't show up. There's also a reference to that GameObject, but when I try to use `uiinquestion.SetActive(true);` I get a null reference exception. It's like this object was deleted at some point, which it isn't, I used the Find All References shortcut in VS 2022 and it only showed `SetActive();` calls on the object, so I'm not setting nor deleting it in any way. It kinda feels like when you have a scene not referenced in the build settings so it isn't included in the build, but I've searched for that and there doesn't seem to be an option doing that, so nothing turned on accidentally there. This is the UI menu in question:

[image: UI Menu in question]

**Question**

Why does this object not exist in the editor but not in the build?

Comment: Is the object a root object, or is it the child in a hierarchy? If it is the latter, does the hierarchy still exist at runtime? Is any of it's parent objects tagged "EditorOnly"? 

You could add some logging to a component on this object to show you what (if anything) happens on Awake, or OnDestroy, to see if it existed but gets deleted at some point.

Comment: I already tried the OnDestroy stuff. The GameObject is a child of a UI Canvas. There are other Panels there too, but they all exist in the build. I'm gonna try the Awake again and see if it shows anything.

Comment: Wait this is interesting: When I put a Debug.Log(); in Awake Method in the script of the object it triggers that event. When I put that Debug.Log in the Update methond it fires once, so the object gets deleted at some point by something.

Comment: Okay, I'm just stupid. I made a thing in my script that deletes any object that is more than 2000 "Units" away, so the UI is included. In the editor, the window is small so the object doesn't get deleted, but when the window is big, bye bye... Thank you for your time!